# Why kGIDSignInErrorCodeUnknown on cancel instead of kGIDSignInErrorCodeCanceled?

Tags: ios, google-signin

When I setup Google Sign-In SDK in my iOS app to disallow logging in with a webView like:

```
[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].allowsSignInWithWebView = NO;
```

and the user touches the cancel button, my `GIDSignInDelegate` method:

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user withError:(NSError *)error
```

gets the error code `kGIDSignInErrorCodeUnknown`.

But when I leave `allowsSignInWithWebView` at the default `YES` I get the `kGIDSignInErrorCodeCanceled` error code.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Just updated to Google Sign-In SDK 2.1.0 and this is still happening.

Comment: Looks like `[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].allowsSignInWithWebView = YES;` now also returns `kGIDSignInErrorCodeUnknown` when the user touches the cancel button. What's the purpose of `kGIDSignInErrorCodeCanceled` then?

Comment: It's not a very nice user experience to have to either display an error or do nothing every time the user returns from Google Sign-In.